# Getting an error "UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'." in Pytorch model deploying in Streamlit

Tags: pytorch, pickle, streamlit

I am trying to deploy my wheat detection model of Pytorch in Streamlit.
But, I am getting an error as

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/streamlit/streamlit.py", line 84, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights_file, map_location=device))
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 529, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 692, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
```

My Github repo is in https://github.com/Anubhav1107/streamlit

PLs write what you want. Thanks for helping !

Comment: I suggest double-checking the binary you are trying to load, i.e., ensure that it is not corrupted, empty, or that indeed you are trying to load a pickled object.

In the past, I have faced this issue when I was trying to run the model from a checkpoint file that was stored on a git LFS that I haven't pulled before. Hence I was using an invalid pickle file.